# Extending string mapping

Tags: c#, strings, functional-programming, operator-overloading

Basically I'm trying to generalise and extend the notion of mapping one string into another.
There are two methods I often find myself using for this: Functions, and Dictionairies.

So here are my 3 classes. (I intend to create some explict classes as well, like ToCamelCase - as my current project requires)

```
public abstract class StringMapping
{
        public string this[string from] 
        {
           get
           {
               return this.Get(from);
           }
        }

        public abstract string Get(string from);

        public static implicit operator Func<string, string>(StringMapping mapping)
        {
            return mapping.Get;
        }

        public ComposableStringMapping AndThen (StringMapping second)
        {
            return new ComposableStringMapping(this, second);
        }

        //An alias for AndThen
        public static ComposableStringMapping operator + (StringMapping first, StringMapping next)
        {
            return first.AndThen(next);
        }
}


public class ComposableStringMapping : StringMapping
{
    private StringMapping _first;
    private StringMapping _andThen;

    public ComposableStringMapping(StringMapping first, StringMapping andThen)
    {
        _first = first;
        _andThen = andThen;
    }

    public override string Get(string from)
    {
        var res = _first[from];
        return _andThen[res];
    }
}

public class FuncStringMapping : StringMapping
{
    private Func<string, string> _underlyingMapping;

    public FuncStringMapping(Func<string, string> underlyingMapping)
    {
        _underlyingMapping = underlyingMapping;
    }

    public FuncStringMapping(StringMapping underlyingMapping)
    {
        _underlyingMapping = underlyingMapping.Get;
    }

    public static implicit operator FuncStringMapping(Func<string, string> underlyingMapping)
    {
        return new FuncStringMapping(underlyingMapping);
    }

    public override string Get(string from)
    {
        return _underlyingMapping(from);
    }
}

public class ExplictStringMapping : StringMapping, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    IDictionary<string, string> _mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void Add(string from,string to)
    {
        _mappings.Add(from,to);
    }

    public override string Get(string from)
    {
        return _mappings.ContainsKey(from) ? _mappings[from] : from;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _mappings.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _mappings.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and here is the nUnit tests / examples of use.

```
[TestFixture]
public class FuncStringMappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldRemoveAllSpaces()
    {
        FuncStringMapping mapping = new FuncStringMapping((string str) => str.Replace(" ", ""));

        Assert.AreEqual(expected: "HelloWorld", actual: mapping["Hello World"]);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldWorkWithSelect()
    {
        const string dest = "crush";
        FuncStringMapping mapping = (FuncStringMapping)(str => dest);
        var src = new List<string> { "alpha", "gamma", "beta" };

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
            expected: Enumerable.Repeat(dest, src.Count()),
            actual: src.Select<string,string>(mapping)
            );
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ExplictStringMappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldMapThingsGivenInIntitilser()
    {
        ExplictStringMapping mapping = new ExplictStringMapping()
        {
            {"1", "one"},
            {"2", "two"},
            {"3", "three"},
        };

        Assert.AreEqual(expected: "two", actual: mapping["2"]);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldMapThingsNotGivenInIntitilserToSelf()
    {
        ExplictStringMapping mapping = new ExplictStringMapping()
        {
            {"1", "one"},
            {"2", "two"},
            {"3", "three"},
        };

        const string unchanged = "alpha";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected: unchanged, actual: mapping[unchanged]);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldWorkWithSelect()
    {
        ExplictStringMapping mapping = new ExplictStringMapping()
        {
            {"1", "one"},
            {"2", "two"},
            {"3", "three"},
        };

        const string unchanged = "alpha";
        var src = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3",unchanged };

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
            expected: new string []{"one","two","three",unchanged},
            actual: src.Select<string,string>(mapping)
            );
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ComposableStringMappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldComposeMappings()
    {
        StringMapping mapping = ((FuncStringMapping)(from => "hello " + from)).AndThen( ((FuncStringMapping)(from => from.ToUpper())));

        Assert.AreEqual(expected: "HELLO JIM", actual: mapping["jim"]);
    }
}
```

Basically I would like for the user not to have to think about whether they are using a function `string foo (string param)` or a StringMapping object. I would like them to be interchangable.

I'm pretty certain there must be a better way, as (can be seen in examples) I keep having to use explicit type cases between the two (incuding giving full type arguments to the LINQ select method).

EDIT:
Another problem is my lack ofa nice inline operator to do the AndThen / compose methood.
Like |> would have been ideal, or >> would work ok. 
The problem with using + is that this is not commititive (then again nor is string concatination. But string concat is obviosly not commutive where as this is a bit more subtle)

Comment: Hmm, try adding an implicit operator to convert `Expression<Func<string, string>>` to `FuncStringMapping`. I think that your issue might be that the compiler does not consider the code `(from => "hello" + from)` to be an actual `Func<string, string>` object; rather, it's a lamba expression that is implicitly convertible to `Func<string, string>`. However, you would still need an explicit cast in order to make your first `.AndThen` call, or you would need to move that call to the next statement after assigning the lambda expression to the mapping variable.

Comment: No, I gave my suggestion a try, and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Wow, this was a terrible idea,. Why did I want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly hackish idea. You can decide whether you want to pollute your codebase with this.  This idea is similar to jQuery, which heavily overloads the $ character to provide a multitude of functionality.

First, define a utility class named "s":

```
public static class s
{
    public static FuncStringMapping Map(Func<string, string> mapping)
    {
        return new FuncStringMapping(mapping);
    }
}
```

Below I've rewritten one of your examples to take advantage of this:

```
        StringMapping mapping = s.Map(from => "hello " + from).AndThen(s.Map(from => from.ToUpper()));
```

Secondly, you could add another Map function that takes any number of `Func<string, string>` arguments, as shown below:

```
public static StringMapping Map(params Func<string, string>[] underlyingMappings)
{
    if (underlyingMappings == null || underlyingMappings.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("underlyingMappings");

    StringMapping mapping = new FuncStringMapping(underlyingMappings[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < underlyingMappings.Length; i++)
    {
        mapping = mapping.AndThen(new FuncStringMapping(underlyingMappings[i]));
    }

    return mapping;
}
```

This allows you to rewrite the above example as follows:

```
StringMapping mapping = s.Map(from => "hello " + from, from => from.ToUpper());
```

I'm not a fan of this approach, because it's hard to read.

Thirdly, you could add extension methods to simplify calls to `.AndThen` when passing in a `Func<string, string>` delegate:

```
public static class FuncStringMappingExtensions
{
    public static StringMapping AndThen(this StringMapping mapping, Func<string, string> andThen)
    {
        return mapping.AndThen(new FuncStringMapping(andThen));
    }
}
```

Building off of the first suggestion, this allows you to rewrite the example as follows:

```
StringMapping mapping = s.Map(from => "hello " + from).AndThen(from => from.ToUpper());
```

---

Addressing your concerns about the need to specify the generic arguments for the Select method, below is the only approach that I can suggest:

First, add an AsDelegate method to your StringMapping class:

```
    public Func<string, string> AsDelegate()
    {
        return this.Get;
    }
```

Next, add an AsDelegate extension method for `Func<string, string>`. The purpose of this is to hide from the developer whether or not their object is a StringMapping object or a `Func<string, string>` object.

```
public static class DelegateExtensions
{
    public static Func<string, string> AsDelegate(this Func<string, string> mapping)
    {
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

This ensures that the developer will always be able to call `.AsDelegate()` on their object, regardless of whether the object is a StringMapping or a `Func<string, string>`.

Naturally, this would require you to call the Select method as follows:

```
        src.Select(mapping.AsDelegate());
```

This may not be the ideal solution, but I don't think that you'll have much luck with tricking the compiler into deriving the generic arguments another way.

Comment: that's no better than the typecasts I'm currently doing. (execpt that it's shorter).

Comment: I think I could also define a extention method:
`public static AsStringMapping(this Func<string,string> mapping)`
`{return new FuncStringMapping(mapping)}`

Comment: @Oxinabox - I agree, it's not much better than explicit casts, but it does at least not require the developer to think "What was the name  of that class again?  Oh, that's right, it's FuncStringMapping."

Comment: Hmm I guess I could have (in the StringMapping Class):
'public static implicit operator StringMapping (Func<string, string>mapping)'
'        { return (FuncStringMapping) mapping; }'
Which would also save the need to s.Map converts a Func to a StringMapping

Comment: I considered the other suggestions also.
An extention to andThen only helps with that one method - it's not scalable.
and an mapping.AsDelegate() is questionably more clear than mapping.Get

Comment: @Oxinabox - Yes, but you can't write `.Get` if the mapping variable is a `Func<string, string>` object.  There is no such "Get" method on a delegate object.  You wanted to a way to keep the developer unconcerned with whether the mapping variable is a `StringMapping` object or a `Func<string, string>` object.  I suppose another idea is that you could create your own `Select` extension method overload that accepts a `StringMapping` object as a parameter.  Perhaps not a great solution, but it would allow you to write `.Select(mapping)`.

Comment: Writing an extention to select has the same problem as writing an extention to AndThen.
It is not solving the problem, just "plugging the leak" (as i'm sure your realise)

Comment: the developer "Knows" that there is no `.AsDelegate()` method on a `Func<string,string>` (This is my big grip with extentsion methods)

Comment: @Oxinabox - I would hope that they do know that.  The issue, though, is that you said that you don't want the developer to "know" whether the mapping variable is of type `StringMapping` or `Func<string, string>`.  If you create the AsDelegate extension method for `Func<string, string>`, then the developer can always call `.AsDelegate()` on the mapping variable, regardless of which type it is.  Not a great solution; I don't think I would go that way, but I'm just trying to explain the merit (what little there is) behind the approach.

Comment: I knew what your were getting at.
I think the best (and impossible solution) would be to Inherit from Func<string,string>